# Node Wrangler Deactivate Solo Node

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to toggle solo mode for a node in Blender Cycles the same way I do it in C4D Octane. In Octane, to enable solo mode you right click the node and choose "Solo", then once you are done, you right click on the node and choose "Disable Solo" to exit solo mode. Simple.

In Blender (with Node Wrangler), enabling solo mode is really easy, you just have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the node. That works really well.

The problem is exiting solo mode. I have to go to the *Principled BSDF* node and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. I was hoping to have something similar like Octane, where I just right click the node I'm soloing and choose disable solo mode.

Having to go to the *Principled BSDF* node and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> is a pain when you are working with deep groups: if I solo a node inside the group, to exit solo mode I have to leave all the nested groups, then go to the *Principled BSDF* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. It's also a pain for complex shaders that have lots of nodes, because you have to scroll to the *Principled BSDF* if it's out of viewport bounds.

My question is:

Is there an easy way to exit solo mode in Node Wrangler, without having to go to the *Principled BSDF* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>? Is there any global shortcut I can press to "exit solo mode" just like in Octane?

Comment: Tried Ctrl-Z ? (AKA global Undo). It does of course mean that you can't carry out any other action that you want to keep in the interim.

Comment: Open a small viewport in the corner and center the principled bsdf there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question.

There are two ways to accomplish this.

### Solution 1: Use two shader editors

As Allen Simpson suggested, you can just have a second shader editor open that has the *Principled BSDF* always in focus and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> it.

### Solution 2: Code

The other way is to write an *Operator* using the Python API:

```
    class Wrangler_Unsolo(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wrangler.unsolo"
    bl_label = "Unsolo"

    def execute(self, context):
        tree = context.space_data.node_tree
        bsdf = tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
        out = tree.nodes['Material Output']
        tree.links.new(bsdf.outputs['BSDF'], out.inputs[0])
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Note that this only works with *Principled BSDF*.